# Extract file names with directory structure into CSV file (separate csv file for each image name)

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, csv, output, file-format

I have a folder structure like :-

```
                                            Type1                                           Type 2      
                                                |                                               |
                    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    |                                       |                                   |                       
                subType1                                 subType2                           subType1             
                    |                                       |                                   |               
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                   |                   |                   |                 |                   |     
        typeA               typeB             typeA               typeB             typeA               typeB   
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   |   |           |    |    |         |   |   |           |   |   |       |   |   |            |    |     |
    F1  F2  F3          F1   F2   F3        F1  F2  F3          F1  F2  F3      F1  F2  F3           F1   F2    F3
            |                     |                                     |                                       |
            |                     |                                     |                                       |
            \/                    \/                                    \/                                      \/
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |       |      |         |       |                      |         |      |                          |       |
    black  red   blue       black   red                     black     red    blue                       black  red
```

In each folder of color some images are there like this :-(and many more )

```
    Type1-subType1-typeA-black-dfsdf1.JPG       Type1-subType1-typeB-black-one.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-red-dfsdf1.JPG         Type1-subType1-typeB-red-one.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-dfsdf1.JPG        Type1-subType1-typeB-black-oh.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-black-2dsfsdf.JPG      Type1-subType1-typeB-red-oh.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-red-2dsfsdf.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-2dsfsdf.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-black-3asdfdf3.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-red-3asdfdf3.JPG
    Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-3asdfdf3.JPG

    Type1-subType2-typeB-black-SSS.JPG      Type2-subType1-typeB-black-5.JPG
    Type1-subType2-typeB-red-SSS.JPG        Type2-subType1-typeB-black-5.JPG
    Type1-subType2-typeB-blue-SSS.JPG       Type2-subType1-typeB-black-565.JPG
    Type1-subType2-typeB-black-AAA.JPG      Type2-subType1-typeB-black-565.JPG
    Type1-subType2-typeB-red-AAA.JPG        
    Type1-subType2-typeB-blue-AAA.JPG
```

I want to read each images and save into individual csv  file. So the csv file format will be:
For folder structure  `Type1-subType1-typeA -dfsdf1.JPG  into file1.csv`

```
          Image name                        |colour | subcat| subtype  | Type1 |
    Type1-subType1-typeA-black-dfsdf1.JPG   | black | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
    Type1-subType1-typeA-red-dfsdf1.JPG     | red   | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
    Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-dfsdf1.JPG    | blue  | typeA | subType1 | Type1 |
```

For folder structure  `Type1-subType1-typeA -2dsfsdf.jpg file2.csv`

```
          Image name                    |colour | subcat| subtype  | Type1 |
Type1-subType1-typeA-black-2dsfsdf.JPG  | black | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-red-2dsfsdf.JPG    | red   | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-2dsfsdf.JPG   | blue  | typeA | subType1 | Type1
```

And So on for other folders also.How can i get the desired out put?

Note: The image name reflects the folder structure.

So far, I've read all images from different folder into a single csv file.
Here is my output:

```
            Image name                  |colour | subcat| subtype  | Type1 |
Type1-subType1-typeA-black-dfsdf1.JPG   | black | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-red-dfsdf1.JPG     | red   | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-dfsdf1.JPG    | blue  | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-black-2dsfsdf.JPG  | black | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-red-2dsfsdf.JPG    | red   | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-2dsfsdf.JPG   | blue  | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-black-3asdfdf3.JPG | black | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-red-3asdfdf3.JPG   | red   | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType1-typeA-blue-3asdfdf3.JPG  | blue  | typeA | subType1 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-black-SSS.JPG      | black | typeB | subType2 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-red-SSS.JPG        | red   | typeB | subType2 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-blue-SSS.JPG       | blue  | typeB | subType2 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-black-AAA.JPG      | black | typeB | subType2 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-red-AAA.JPG        | red   | typeB | subType2 | Type1 | 
Type1-subType2-typeB-blue-AAA.JPG       | blue  | typeB | subType2 | Type1 |
```

Please suggest how can I achieve my desired output.

Comment: Wow. Kudos for effort in making that ASCII structure map. Next time though, you might want to think about just using `tree` instead.

Comment: Actually. Please do use `tree`, your ASCII is hard to follow. What are `F1`, `F2` etc? If directories, why don't they appear in your csv? Are the image names always the same?

Comment: @terdon F1,F2 also directories.All Images in that directories, so that path is constant.In image name it(directories name) will not be there.Image name will be same but color,sub-folder,type  will be different .So image 1 name should be in one csv file, image 1 name should be in second csv file, and so on

Comment: How to use tree for folder structure can you please explain

Comment: Just run the command `tree` from the parent directory of `Type1` and `Type2`. It will print the directory structure for you.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for such useful information.

Answer (score 0):

as a rule, you shouldn't parse output of ls, however assuming you have no 'funny' names (like space or line break).

I would use awk to parse file name

```
ls | awk -F- '{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n",$0,$4,$3,$2,$1}' > file.csv
```

where

- `-F-` tell awk to use - as separator
- `$0` whole line
- `$4..$1` -th field